# How to externalize a proc in assembly x86?

Tags: assembly

I am wondering how I would go about externalizing a proc (example below) so I can use it when compiling two separate file together

```
FOOBAR PROC
    ;do something
    RET
FOOBAR ENDP
```

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of assembler do you use?

Also, you _compile_ translation units, but you _link_ objects together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extern foobar:proc

There's also a 'proto' directive to do an extern definition of a procedure that includes parameters so you can use 'invoke' to pass parameters to it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to export it in stdcall format you need to call it in proper format:

_ProcedureName@0 (VOID procedure)
_ProcedureName@16 (16 = 4x DWORD parameters)